# Ruby and Rails have stopped working completely on my machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been learning Ruby slowly over the last few weeks, and have been making methods using Sublime Text 2.  I've been running these scripts in the terminal command line

```
ruby file_name.rb
```

These scripts have been running great in the terminal.  I then wanted to start using Rails, so updated my current Rails version using RVM.  However during install I kept getting error messages about needing Xcode or command line tools to be installed (both of which were installed).  I quit out of that installation, and went back to testing out some ruby stuff.

However, now ruby and rails don't work at all.  Even running

```
ruby -v
```

Nothing happens.  I don't get a warning or an error, but my terminal simply switches the top bar from bash to env and back and forth constantly without anything happening.  It just displays an empty line and not another command line.  I then have to quit out of the script by pressing Control-C.

What happened?  I tried reinstalling ruby but it's not working.  I'm really confused...

Comment: what `type rvm | head -2` shows? what `which ruby` shows?

Comment: RVM was probably the wrong approach. I'd just stick to using `gem` to handling packages. It makes life easier.

Comment: RVM is fine. gem doesn't handle multiple Rubies, only gems. The problem is probably bailing out part-way.

Comment: how can I fix this if I did bail out part way?  Nothing works right now.  "which ruby" gives back: "/Users/MyName/.rvm/bin/ruby"

Comment: Did you add anything to your bash profile? If not, it shouldn't be activating RVM. Try typing ruby -v into a new terminal window.

Comment: I've got the same problem. It doesn't matter where I enter "ruby -v", it's always the same. After waiting some time I get the following 2 errors: .rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long AND .rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0. Before the error messages there is a path to my home directory.